# Configure Spring Data JPA custom repository impl using Java Config

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data

I'm using Spring Boot and Spring Data JPA. I want to create a custom repository method, as described in the reference. I need a reference to the EntityManager in the custom method. When the CustomRepositoryImpl class has an @Autowired/@Inject field, it works fine. What I would like to do is to have this bean configured using JavaConfig. Is this possible? My attempts have been failing so far, here is my code:

```
public interface CustomerRepositoryCustom {

    void resetAll();
}

public class CustomerRepositoryImpl implements CustomerRepositoryCustom {

    //    @Inject
    private EntityManager em;

    public CustomerRepositoryImpl(EntityManager em) {
        this.em = em;
    }

    @Transactional
    @Override
    public void resetAll() {
        // some code
    }
}
```

In my @SpringBootApplication class, which is by definition a @Configuration class, I have a @Bean definition like this one:

```
@Bean
public CustomerRepositoryCustom customerRepositoryCustom(EntityManager em) {
    return new CustomerRepositoryImpl(em);
}
```

This doesn't work, this method is completely ignored, and I get the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: test.CustomerRepositoryImpl.<init>()
```

i.e. Spring Data doesn't look at the @Bean definition, it just tries to create the custom repo bean itself with the default constructor, which doesn't exist.

Is it possible to instruct Spring Data to use the @Bean method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue I think is the name of the bean, it should be named `customerRepositoryImpl` which in the case of JavaConfig it is not, if you change the javaconfig to this, it should work:

```
@Bean
public CustomerRepositoryCustom customerRepositoryImpl(EntityManager em) {
    return new CustomerRepositoryImpl(em);
}
```

Comment: Yes! This works fine, and so does this: @Bean(name = "customerRepositoryImpl"). Thank you. I am very confused about the resolution, though - how did you know the bean name must be different? I don't recall reading anything along these lines in the Spring Data (JPA) documentations, could you explain where did you find this rule?

Comment: Ok, I found the relevant documentation entry, it's in §3.6.1, under the section 'Manual wiring'.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried?

```
@Repository
class MyCustomerRepo implements CrudRepository<User,Long>, CustomerRepositoryCustom{
}
class CustomerRepositoryCustomImpl implements CustomerRepositoryCustom{
private EntityManager em;

@Inject
public CustomerRepositoryImpl(EntityManager em) {
    this.em = em;
}

@Transactional
@Override
public void resetAll() {
    // some code
}
}
```

also remove your @bean  definition

**edit:**

```
@autowired
EntityManager em;

@Bean
public CustomerRepositoryCustom customerRepositoryCustom() {
    return new CustomerRepositoryImpl(em);
}
```

Comment: Yes, I had tried that and it works, it also would work with setter injection, but that's not the point of my question, it still requires the annotation and is not done with Java Config. I explicitly don't want it to work with @Bean.

Comment: Then have you tired to autowire yot EntityManager on the @ SpringBootApplication class and remove it from the parameters of your bean definition? according to this documentation http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-java-injecting-imported-beans

Comment: And how is this supposed to help? If I remove it from the bean definition, how will it get the reference to it so that it is usable from within the custom methods? The custom repo needs to get the EntityManager somehow, and any @Bean method to create it is simply ignored.

Comment: look at the linked documentation, it passes a datasource, instead of that just autowire a EntityManager

Comment: This doesn't work. I don't need to define an \@Autowired field in the \@Configuration class as \@Bean method parameters are injected anyways, and so the EntityManager will just be there, provided by the container. You clearly didn't test your code.